# Google Speech To Text API Performance in NodeJS App

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, cloud, speech-to-text

I am using a NodeJS App to make a call to the Speech-To-Text API of Google Cloud. It works, but the performance is horrible. Did anyone find a way (for example using optional parameters) to enhance the performance?
A call is taking 20-25 seconds for a 15 seconds wav file. Also the quality of transcription is quite bad. It's only lower case, no sentence structure whatsoever. I realized that the response includes more alternatives to the transcription. Is there a way to only get the best one (that suits my use case)?
I think I might not be using it right. For example I tried openAI's "whisper" which is giving far better results in quality and quantity.
Also google sometimes gives me a failed response, because the audio is longer than 1 minute, which is not true.

Here's how I'm doing the request:

```
    public transcribeAudio() {
        return new Promise<String>((resolve, reject): void => {
            const filePath = "files/audio.wav"
            const google = new SpeechClient();

            const file = readFileSync(filePath);
            const audioBytes = file.toString('base64'); 

            const audio = {
                content:audioBytes, 
              };

            const config = {
                encoding: 'LINEAR16' as any,
                sampleRateHertz: 16000,
                languageCode: 'de-DE',
              };
            
              const request = {
                audio: audio,
                config: config,
                apiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_KEY, 
              };

              const options = {
                maxResults: 1
              }


              try {
                const response = await google.recognize(request, options);
                const transcription = response[0];
                
                infoMessage('Transkription: ' + transcription);
                resolve(transcription.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript)
              } catch (error) {
                reject(error)
              }
            })
        })
    }
```